# Not able to communicate with the ms via gateway

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I use spring cloug gateway with eureka.

My GatewayConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {
    @Bean
    public ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory(CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry) {
        ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory = new ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory();
        reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory.configureCircuitBreakerRegis    try(circuitBreakerRegistry);
        return reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r
                        .host("/accounts/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.circuitBreaker(config -> config
                                .setName("account")
                                .setFallbackUri("forward:/fallback")))
                        .uri("lb://account-service"))
                
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I connect to my eureka server, I see my ACCOUNT-SERVICE application

I'm able to communicate directly with my account service.

When I try to connect via gateway

http://localhost:9000/accounts/1

I get a 404

But that work if I do the call directly to the ms
http://localhost:8001/accounts/1

Config of the gateways

```
server.port=9000
spring.application.name=gateway
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.sliding-window-size=100
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=30
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.waitDurationInOpenState=1s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.eventConsumerBufferSize=10


resilience4j.timelimiter.time-limiter-aspect-order=398
resilience4j.timelimiter.configs.default.timeout-duration=1s
resilience4j.timelimiter.configs.default.cancel-running-future=false
```

Dependencies of Gateways

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
```

Dependencies of my service

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
 implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
```

In my Gateways, Every five minute, I see

Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration

I done config of the project with spring initializer...

I get

implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'

I updated to

implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j'

that work

Comment: Please show your dependencies. Also are there any relevant logs in gateway?

Comment: I updated with you request